# Use nested Schema with allow_blank in marshmallow

Tags: python, validation, nested, marshmallow

I'm stuck with a problem and I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.
I'd like to use marshmallow to validate a structure with a nested schema.
Here is an example:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
class userAddress(Schema):
    street = fields.Str(required=True)
    city = fields.Str(required=False)
    zipcode = fields.Int(required=True)
    

class user(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    address = fields.Nested(userAddress, required=False, allow_none=True, allow_blank=True)

user_instance = user()

user_data1 = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "Road to nowhere",
        "city": "St. Elsewhere",
        "zipcode": 666
    }
}

user_data2 = {
    "name": "John Doe, Jr.",
    "address": {}
}
```

What I would like to achieve, is that both user_data dicts are validated without a problem. If the key `address` is present the corresponding dictionary should match the definitions in schema `userAddress`. But it is acceptable if the key `address` is not present or the value is an empty dictionary.

However this is not working, here is the result:

```
>>> user_instance.validate(user_data1)
{}
>>> user_instance.validate(user_data2)
{'address': {'zipcode': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'street': ['Missing data for required field.']}}
>>>
```

The empty dictionary for `address` in user_data2 is not accepted.

I tried to use `partial=True` in `validate` but then a missing `name` is accepted, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try fields.Raw() instead of Nested()

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
class userAddress(Schema):
    street = fields.Str(required=True)
    city = fields.Str(required=False)
    zipcode = fields.Int(required=True)
    

class user(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    address = fields.Raw(userAddress)

user_instance = user()

user_data1 = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "Road to nowhere",
        "city": "St. Elsewhere",
        "zipcode": 666
    }
}

user_data2 = {
    "name": "John Doe, Jr.",
    "address": {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruta. Thanks for the reply. However, I get an error message when I'm trying your version.  `address = fields.Raw(userAddress, required=False, allow_none=True)` `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 2 keyword-only arguments) were given`

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to clean up empty dicts before loading it:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pre_load

class userAddress(Schema):
    street = fields.Str(required=True)
    city = fields.Str(required=False)
    zipcode = fields.Int(required=True)


class user(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    address = fields.Nested(userAddress, required=False, allow_none=True)

    @pre_load
    def clearemptydicts(self, data, **kwargs):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict) and len(v) == 0:
                data[k] = None
        return data


user_instance = user()

user_data1 = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "Road to nowhere",
        "city": "St. Elsewhere",
        "zipcode": 666
    }
}

user_data2 = {
    "name": "John Doe, Jr.",
    "address": {}
}
print(user_instance.validate(user_data1))
print(user_instance.validate(user_data2))
```

Comment: or mybe you want to pop the whole key/value